# Preserve Order for Cross Validation in Weka

Tags: weka, cross-validation

I am using the Weka GUI for classifying sensor data.

I have measures of 10 people, the data is sorted. So the first 10% correspond to participant 1, the second 10% to participant 2 etc.

I would like to use 10 fold cross validation to build a model on 9 participants and test it on the remaining participant. In my case I believe I could accomplish this by simply not randomizing the data splits.

How would I best go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this in the Explorer.

In the **KnowledgeFlow** GUI, there is a **CrossValidationFoldMaker** used to create cross-validation folds.  This has an option to **Preserve instances order**, which says it preserves the order of instances rather than randomly shuffling.

There's a video describing the KnowledgeFlow interface here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHSgoVX9z-8&t=7s